# How is sib byte formed in x86 processor?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, machine-code

In x86 SIB, if index = 100, scale and index register not used, it means that 24, 64 , A4 , E4 and other may be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think that's right.  The 2-bit scale field is unused if there's no index register so you can use any of the 4 possible values there.

I didn't check the actual hex values to make sure you got the right final values.